# Google Universal Analytics Enhanced Ecommerce add to cart quantity

Tags: google-analytics

I've set up google analytics enhanced ecommerce and created a function for adding the product to the cart.

```
function addCart() {
    ga('ec:addProduct', {
        'id': '{{ product.product.id }}',
        'name' : '{{ product.product.name }}',
        'category' : '{{ product.product.category.name }}',
        'brand' : '{{ product.manufacturer.name }}',
        'price': '{{ product.product.price }}',
        'quantity': 20
    });

    ga('ec:setAction', 'add');
    ga('send', 'event', 'UX', 'click', 'add');
}
```

However when i add a product to the cart it doesn't matter what I set the quantity to, it always adds just one of that product to the cart in GA, shouldn't it add say 20 products to cart if i set the quantity to 20?

Comment: Looks good to me. When you call the function and check in the console, do you see the collect hit going through? If so, what does it say, specifically the product parameters (pr1id, pr1nm, pr1ca, pr1br, pr1pr, pr1qt).

Comment: Yes, i see the collect hit and the product parameters. However, pr1qt is not included.

Comment: What i want is that if i add more than one of the same product in to the cart it shouldn't give me just one hit for that product in GA. Right? If i add 20 of one product in the cart then GA should give me 20 hits on added to cart for that product. It just gives me one at the moment. And at this point the "quantity: 20" in my code example is just for testing, i will of course make it so it changes dynamically depending on what the customer has chosen.

Comment: You should see the pr1qt parameter. If not, then there is something wrong. (I basically copy and pasted your code into the console, after substituting in values, and it returned those parameters.)